# Creating Angular.js directives containing other directives

Tags: angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I am trying to come up with a library of re-usable directives. First two directives I tried to implement are DatePicker and DateRangePicker. The DateRangePicker must contain two DatePickers.

I want DatePicker to have a signature similar to:

```
<div cx-date-picker="" cx-label="myLabel" 
     cx-id="myDate" cx-source="myDateVarInScope"></div>
```

and I want DateRangePicker to look like this:

```
<div cx-date-range-picker cx-id="searchRangePicker" 
     cx-source="myDateRangeInScope"></div>
```

where myDateRangeInScope contains members: startDate and endDate

I looked at a few examples of how to create directives but I can't figure out how to pass parameters into underlying directives. Here is the code for DatePicker

```
angular.module('ng').directive('cxDatePicker', function () {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: 'isolate',
        template: '<div class="control-group input-append">' +
        '<label for="{{theId}}" class="label">{{theLabel}}</label>' +
        '<input id="{{theId}}" class="input-small" type="text" ' + 
        'ng-model="theSource" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" bs-datepicker>' +
        '<button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="datepicker">' +
        '<i class="icon-calendar"></i></button>' +
        '</div>',

        link: function (scope, iterStartElement, attr) {
          var theId = attr['cxId'];
          scope.theLabel = attr['cxLabel']
          scope.theId = attr['cxId'];
          scope.theSource = attr['cxSource'];
        }
      };
    });
```

which displays proper values for *theId* and *theLabel* but doesn't display correct date.

And this is the code for DateRangePicker, which fails to set attributes for underlying DatePickers.

```
angular.module('ng').directive('cxDateRangePicker', function () {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: 'isolate',
        template: '<div cx-date-picker="" cx-source="{{startSource}}" ' +
          'cx-label="{{fromLabel}}" cx-id="{{startId}}"></div>' +
          '<div cx-date-picker="" cx-source="{{endSource}}" cx-label="{{toLabel}}" ' +
          ' cx-id="{{endId}}"></div>',
        link: function (scope, iterStartElement, attr) {
          var theId = attr['cxId'];
          scope.startId = theId + "From";
          scope.endId = theId + "To";
          scope.fromLabel = "From";
          scope.toLabel = "To";
          scope.startSource = attr['cxSource'] + ".startDate";
          scope.endSource = attr['cxSource'] + ".endDate";

        }
      };
    });
```

Can anyone point me to a solution? I saw that link() methods of underlying DatePickers are called before link() method of DateRangePicker. Therefore no wonder the values are not passed. But I lack overall conceptual understanding to solve the problem. Official docs didn't help much.

In general, did anyone try to achieve a similar goal - to build directives on top of other directives and by doing it, build a business domain-specific component library?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=WqmeI5fZcho#!
Here is a nice video, which clarifies a lot

Comment: Why not using Element directive instead of Attribute?

Answer (score 3):

The point is in using properly using the scope.
The **@** attribute just copies values from tag attributes statically, instead you should use the **=** attribute which links parent scope variables with directive scope ones.
I've created [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4Z9XFJP3m9FEqGNZ9Pfv) to show you how to correctly implement both directives.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is in handling scope. Which means that Angular.js indeed has a sound component architecture allowing to build larger components on top of smaller ones. This is a good progress compared to Backbone. I am wondering if Ember.js has similar capabilities.

```
angular.module('ng').directive('cxDatePicker', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: 
      {
        cxLabel: '@',
        cxId: '@',
        cxSource: '='
      },
    template: '<div class="control-group input-append">' +
    '<label for="{{cxId}}" class="label" style="margin-right: 6px;">{{cxLabel}}</label>' +
    '<input id="{{cxId}}" class="input-small" type="text" ng-model="cxSource" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" bs-datepicker>' +
    '<button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="datepicker"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></button>' +
    '</div>',

    link: function (scope, iterStartElement, attr) {}
  };
});


angular.module('ng').directive('cxDateRangePicker', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: 
      {
        cxId: '@',
        cxSource: '='
      },
    template: '<div cx-date-picker="" cx-source="cxSource.startDate" cx-label="From" cx-id="{{cxId}}From" ></div>' +
      '<div cx-date-picker="" cx-source="cxSource.endDate" cx-label="To" cx-id="{{cxId}}To" ></div>',
    link: function (scope, iterStartElement, attr) {}
  };
});
```